# How can I set custom datetime pattern on Bokeh hover formatter?

Tags: python, plot, hover, data-visualization, bokeh

I'm trying to plot some values respect to the time using a line plot with Bokeh. My issue came when I tried to add a hover that shows the concrete value at some point of the plot.

I want to show a `value, time` data (it works fine), but I think a `yyyy-mm-dd` is imprecise for my purpose, so I want to redefine that pattern to add hours and minutes.

My code is something like that (you can download as a notebook [here](https://github.com/garciparedes/python-examples/blob/master/notebooks/bokeh-datetime-hover.ipynb)):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


today = datetime.today()

date_range = pd.date_range(today, today + timedelta(days=1),
                           freq=timedelta(minutes=15))
values = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=len(date_range)).cumsum()
data = pd.DataFrame({'date': date_range, 'value': values})


hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('value',   '@value'), ('date', '@date{%F}')],
                  formatters={'date': 'datetime'})

plt = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', tools=[hover])

plt.line(x='date', y='value', source=data)

show(plt)
```

The output is like that:

[image: Plot]

So my question is as follows:

Can anyone explain me how to modify the datetime format pattern on the hover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the time in hours and minutes by adding `%H:%M` to `@date`, like this:

```
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('value',   '@value'), ('date', '@date{%F %H:%M}')],
                  formatters={'date': 'datetime'})
```

The scales are described in the [DatetimeTickFormatter](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For supplyment：*bokeh version 2.4.1*

- **1):** Just put "@" in `formatters`:

```py
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('value',   '@value'), ('date', '@date{%F}')],
                  formatters={'@date': 'datetime'})
```

[image]

------------line------------------

- **2):** You can supply a **custom** HTML template for a tooltip: [link:boke org guid](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html)

```py
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips="""
            <div>
                <h3>@date{%F}</h3>
                <div>
                    <strong>value: </strong>
                    <span style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; color: #696;">@value</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            """,
    formatters={'@date': 'datetime'},
    mode='vline'
)
```

[image]